# Issue concatenating @items['FolderName'] in ARM template

Tags: azure

\Can anyone help with regard to concatenating shared path with list of file names in ARM template

Example (Shared Path): \HostName\MySharedPath\Root
The above is stored as parameter in ARM template

When we try to concenate as below
"concat[parameters('SharedPath'), @items['Folder Name')] we are facing error

Can someone help how to define the above in ARM template

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems that you are using:

```
concat[parameters('SharedPath'), @items['Folder Name')]
```

Instead of:

```
concat(parameters('SharedPath'), @items('Folder Name'))
```